# AS3-What's the difference between "rotation" and "rotationZ"?

Tags: actionscript-3

Both of them, do the same. so, are they completely same as each other or there is difference?

Comment: One is rotating in 2D space, the other 3D space.    If in 3D space there is no other rotation involved on other axis,  rotationZ will be effectively the same as rotation of a 2D object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually they are the same, but there is some difference to be aware of.

Display objects can either be 2d (`transform.matrix`) or 3d (`transform.matrix3D`), but not both. The `rotation` property reflects rotation of the `matrix` or `matrix3D`, while `rotationZ` explicitly represents rotation around the Z axis of the `matrix3D` property. The difference here is that if you set `rotationZ` it will, like all 3d properties (`z`, `rotationX`, etc), convert the display object to 3d (`transform.matrix3D`) even if no other 3d properties are set. For example:

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

sprite.rotation = 50;
trace(sprite.transform.matrix); // [object Matrix]
trace(sprite.transform.matrix3D) // null

sprite.rotationZ = 50;
trace(sprite.transform.matrix); // null
trace(sprite.transform.matrix3D) // [object Matrix3D]
```

This is notable because the 3d rendering (`transform.matrix3D`) does introduce some blurring due to the way 3d is projected onto 2d, while 2d rendering (`transform.matrix`) does not.

So, if you aren't going to use any other 3d properties, stick to `rotation`. If you are going to use other 3d properties, using `rotationZ` makes more sense.

Other than that, they are the same. ;)

Hope that helps.

Comment: so that's the difference.Thank you.